# are user facebook "access token" permanent and unique?

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication

I'm building an android app.

I want to create a unique id for each user.

What "tokens" are send from FB after successful login?

(i heard terms such as "access token", "sessionToken" , "open-auth token", "SSO token")?

Are they unique and permanent so I can use them as a unique id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "access token" and no, they are not permanent so I would not use them for a user id.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

You would be better off using the facebook user id for your 'unique id'.