# Concerns about Facebook integration in website. access-token

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, authentication, passport.js

First of all I use express and passport. I was wondering if I go with that method why I don't need to include the javascript "SDK" that a read about on the developer site. I'm a little confused why passport doesn't discuss the SDK. I guess because the SDK is for client side and there is another way to do the same thing with Oauth and that is what `passport-facebook` uses. I would like more details on that.

Also about the access-token.

In passport I do something like this:

`function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){`

`...`

`newUser.facebook.token = accessToken;`

This gets an "acccesToken" like this = EAAYrf9ixTA0BAPkSlXymZA3y2QwkDIlAB84XXCjQH2qxEgZAaP8kdZBqWZApZAd5ZCqyD4te6YkZAYTpMPGujYq88fRZC2HcrcgfzLBiFyIMXrRUpssNxW470SJ7muNkiZCKEDoejiSZBgvtJkQen8rnr2nctEvfzfUm

**I was wondering if this is different for every user?**

[It](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) says that there are 4 different types of "access-tokens" which one is the one above? and how do you know?

Also, I thought I read in the SDK guide that it would set the accessToken in the cookies but I don't see it
This is what I get when I do `console.log(req.session)`

```
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  passport: { user: '5760703f8fd744e020920980' } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why don't I need the Facebook Javascript SDK with PassportJS?

Facebook's client-side SDK allows you to get authentication (`FB.api('/me')`) and session data (`FB.getLoginState`) directly from Facebook and set it in the client-side's cookies.  When using Passport, passport.js handles the authentication call when you call `passport.authenticate` in your routes and session data automatically, but all from the server-side, and with less code on your part.

Also, Facebook will only give short-lived access tokens for web logins, but will give long-term access tokens to server requests.

2. Is the access token different for every user?

Is it unique? Yes. I haven't seen it explicitly stated, but Facebook says that:

> One important aspect to understand about access token is that they are portable. Once you have an access token you can use it to make calls from a mobile client, a web browser, or from your server to Facebook's servers. If a token is obtained on a client, you can ship that token down to your server and use it in server-to-server calls. If a token is obtained via a server call, you can also ship that token up to a client and then make the calls from the client.

What I think you might be actually asking is **is it persistent**, and [the answer is no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444200/are-user-facebook-access-token-permanent-and-unique).  They will expire and be regenerated.

> Short-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about an hour or two, while long-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about 60 days. You should not depend on these lifetimes remaining the same - the lifetime may change without warning or expire early.

3. Which type of access token is it and how do you know?

It is a [User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens).  Passport deals with user logins and user authentication and returns user profile information, not any information associated with the other 3 token types.

> The user token is the most commonly used type of token. This kind of access token is needed any time the app calls an API to read, modify or write a specific person's Facebook data on their behalf. User access tokens are generally obtained via a login dialog and require a person to permit your app to obtain one.

4. The SDK says the accessToken is set in cookies.

Passport doesn't explicitly store the accessToken in the session, it generally stores a unique identifier to the user, such as `user._id`, when `passport.session()` calls `passport.serializeUser`, so that a user object can be found when `passport.deserializeUser` is called.  You can read more in "[What does passport.session() middleware do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052258/what-does-passport-session-middleware-do)".